# Format long Timestamp

Tags: java, timestamp

I use this code to get the timestamp, cast it to long, and put it in the database.

```
Timestamp timeStamp = new Timestamp(date.getTime());
long lonTime = timeStamp.getTime();
DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
Entity post = new Entity("post");
post.setProperty("time", lonTime);
datastore.put(post);
```

The time I stored looks to something like time = 1372369544272.
Now when I get it, how can I format it to get the date and the time?

Comment: TimeStamp t = new Timestamp(longtime); Have you checked this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5928650/how-to-change-a-long-variable-to-a-timestamp-in-java

Comment: [This is how it's done in javascript.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8947322/1708136)

Comment: First,you should know that TimeStamp is extends from Date. So you can do like: get the TimeStamp by TimeStamp t = new TimeStamp(long) ; Same as get the Date by  Date d = new Date(long); When you want to get format like "ddMMM",using SimpleDateFormat, using Calendar to do some calculate work about date

Answer (score 0):

To get back the `Date` and `Time` from the timestamp you need to do pass the long value in the `Timestamp` constructor like -  `Timestamp t = new Timestamp(1372369544272L)`.

Have a look at the `Timestamp` [java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html) for more details.